# Convergence of the factorial function?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

How can you show the convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{x!}^{\epsilon}} dx$ for all $\epsilon$>$0$
If it's at all possible.

My thoughts and attempt was to first replace $x!$ with $\Gamma(x+1)$, since $x!$ only maps naturals to naturals.
So,
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$$
And now attempt to do the comparrison test, say, $2^{x}$. I could not find a function that is everywhere less than the factorial function that also converges, maybe i'm missing something. But here is my attempt.

I found the first integer in the domain $[1,\infty)$ such that $2^{x} < \Gamma(x+1)$ which I got to be $x=4$. Then I took the integral and split it up.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx = \int_{1}^{4} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx + \int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$$

Now, knowing that $2^x$ is less than $\Gamma(x+1)$ on the interval $[4,\infty)$, we now have that $$\frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}} < \frac {1}{2^{x\epsilon}}$$
and so $$\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx < \int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{2}^{x\epsilon}}dx < \infty$$

And now finally, because $\int_{1}^{4} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$ certainly converges to some finite value, and $\int_{4}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx$ converges to some other finite value by the comparison, then adding them together should show that the entire integral
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{\Gamma(x+1)}^{\epsilon}}dx < \infty$$ and converges for any $\epsilon >0$ and then in a sense, so must $\frac{1}{x!}$

Correct?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: A starting place is: $2^x < x! \implies (x!)^{-\epsilon} < 2^{-x\epsilon}$

Comment: I was thinking that. But $x!$ is not *always* greater.
Am i allowed to split the integral up into two parts 
$\int_{1}^{a} \frac {1} {{x!}^\epsilon} + \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac {1} {{x!}^\epsilon}$
Where a is the point that x! becomes greater than the function i'm comparing it to? And then look at the interval from $a$ to $\infty$ and see if that converges?

Comment: Yes, that would be next step which is to split it so to raise the $x$ to meet the inequality bound.